# cross instance calculations in django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Not sure that it's (a) doable and (b) if I formulate the task correctly. Perhaps the right way is refactoring the db design, but I would appreciate any opinion on that.

I have a model in django app, where I track the times a user enters and exits a certain page (via either form submission or just closing the broswer window). I do tracking using django channels, but it does not matter in this case.

The model looks like:

```
class TimeStamp(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'enter_time'

    page_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(to=Participant, related_name='timestamps')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    enter_exit_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=ENTEREXITTYPES,)
```

What I need to do is to calculate how much time a user spends on this page. So I need to loop through all records of `Timestamp` for the specific user, and calculate time difference between records of 'enter' and 'exit' types records.

So the db data may look like:

```
id  timestamp  enter_exit_type
1  20:12:12  enter
2  20:12:13  exit
3  20:18:12  enter
4  20:21:12  exit
5  20:41:12  enter
```

so what is the right way to produce a resulting queryset that look like:

```
id  time_spent_sec  
1  0:01  
2  3:00
```

The last 'enter' record is ignored because there is no corresponding 'exit' record. 
The record 1 in resulting queryset is difference between timestamps in ids 2 and 1. The record 2 in resulting queryset is difference between timestamps in ids 4 and 3.

I can just loop through the records, looking for the nearest 'exit' record and calculate it but I was thinking if there is a simpler solution?

Comment: What is `type` ?

Comment: Sorry it’s actually called event_type. It’s either enter or exit (depending on if a person enters the page at this time or exits)

Comment: is that `enter_exit_type` in model for?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You are right. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: It is possible, with a subquery, but it will typically run in (n log n) or quadratic time, and it would require to set an index on `timestamp` (in order to process it rather fast).

Comment: Furthermore it is probably not a good idea to use a `CharField` here. You can for example use an `IntegerField`, and specify `choices`.

Comment: Furthermore is this for a *specific* user, or for *all* users?

Comment: For a specific user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible:

1) Use the approach [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) to group by user if you want to get answer for all users in one query.

2) filter out the last *unclosed* entry with `enter_exit_type == 'enter'`.

3) .annotate(timestamp_with_sign=Case(When(enter_exit_type='exit', then=*F('timestamp')* * -1), default=*F('timestamp')*, )

4) Sum() by the timestamp_with_sign field.

I'm not sure, that F('timestamp') would work, you may need to search for the way to convert it to unix time.

Answer (score 0):

This model structure may not be sufficient for your requirement. So I would suggest to change your model as,

```
class TimeStamp(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'enter_time'

    page_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Musician, related_name='timestamps')
    enter = models.DateTimeField()
    exit = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Then you will get the data as,

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum, ExpressionWrapper, DurationField

TimeStamp.objects.values(
    'participant').annotate(
    sum_time_diff=Sum(
        ExpressionWrapper(F('exit') - F('enter'), output_field=DurationField())
    )
)
```

The response be like,

```
<QuerySet [{'participant': 1, 'sum_time_diff': datetime.timedelta(0, 7)}, {'participant': 2, 'sum_time_diff': datetime.timedelta(0, 2)}]>
```

Comment: You need to exclude those, where `exit is None`